# Русский язык в LaTeX

Tags: latex, вёрстка

Как сверстать в LaTeX документ с русским текстом?
Проблема в том, что при добавлении русского текста меняется гарнитура шрифта со стандартной на что-то другое. И это что-то другое выглядит отвратительно: в 100-процентном масштабе текст выглядит слишком "тонким", "светлым", а при увеличении неровным.
Скриншот:
[image]

Разница, как видно, большая

Код текста со скриншота:

> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[english,ngerman,russian]{babel}

Comment: Возможно, ваши шрифты просто плохо [охинтованы](http://www.paratype.com/services/truetypehinting.pdf). А как на печати, качество тоже упало? ТеХ ориентирован больше на печать.

Comment: Если эти русские шрифты плохо охинтованы, то есть ли какой-либо другой пакет с кириллическими шрифтами?
Про печать не знаю, пока не проверил...

Comment: А целиком текст примера не приведёте? Возможно, что шрифты вообще растровые.

Answer (score 1):

Решено установкой пакета cm-super.